# ${x^*}Bx \in R$ for all $x \in {C^n}$. Why $B = {B^*}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If ${x^*}Bx \in R$  for all $x \in {C^n}$ and $B \in {M_n}$. Why $B = {B^*}$ ?

Comment: Did you try to solve this problem? What worked, what did not?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $y$ is a real number, what is $y^*$?

Comment: ${y^*} = \overline {{y^T}}$